# docker-compose using cached file with pytest

Tags: intellij-idea, docker-compose, pytest

I've configured IntelliJ to use python via a stack I've defined in docker-compose. I'm configured my project to execute my pytest via docker-compose so that I can use the debugger. However, I've discovered that after the initial run, when I change my code and re-run my tests, pytest is not seeing my changes, but rather executing a cached version of the code.

[image]

The only way I've discovered to get around this is to invoke the **File** menu option **Invalidate Caches and Restart**. This is annoying.

This my compose file:

```
networks:
  app: {}
services:
  item-set-definitions:
    build:
      context: /Users/kudrykma/ghoildex/kudrykma/analytics/sa-item-set-definitions
      target: build
    command:
    - /bin/bash
    image: item-sets:test
    networks:
      app: {}
    volumes:
    - source: /Users/kudrykma/ghoildex/kudrykma/analytics/sa-item-set-definitions
      target: /project
      type: bind
version: '3.9'
```

In the pytest Run configuration I've tried adding `-force-recreate` option in the docker-compose **Command and options** field but IntelliJ won't recognize it.

Does anyone know how I can configure IntelliJ to not cache any of my source file so that pytest will see my changed code?

Thank you

Comment: is your dockerignore set up properly?

Comment: If you have reliable steps to reproduce the issue, consider filing an issue to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/py, as it looks like a bug.

Comment: I have raised this as an issue with Jetbrains.